# Computing min and max using median of 3 elements

Tags: algorithms, searching

How can I write an O(n)-time algorithm to find the minimum and maximum,  given a list of n elements drawn from a totally ordered set using the subroutine median3(x,y,z) which returns the index of three elements x,y,z?  You are not allowed to read or compare the elements directly; the only operation that is allowed is invoke the median3 subroutine.

Comment: If you'd like to make changes, please don't re-post your question in a new post.  Instead, edit the existing question using the 'edit' link under the question.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let the list be $x_1,\ldots,x_n$. The algorithm is as follows:

1. Let $S = \{x_1,x_2\}$.
2. For $i = 3,\ldots, n$:

   - Add $x_i$ to $S$.
   - Compute the median of $S$, and remove it from $S$.
3. Output $S$.

I'll let you figure out why this works.

Note that we cannot possibly tell which is the minimum and which is the maximum. Indeed, $\operatorname{median3}$ works the same for both the original order and its reverse.